# How to turn all features off when clicking the back button in the custom setup dialog?

Tags: installshield

My features have an install level of 150 by default.

In my setup type dialog I turn some features on like this:

[image]

This uses the built in AddLocal event, but there is no RemoveLocal event.

When the user clicks back, I want all the features disabled again.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the 'Remove' event. These actually correspond to the various MSI feature-related properties (ADDLOCAL, REMOVE, etc.).

Comment: I would say it translates the other way; the various feature-related properties are processed to set feature states; the control events set them directly.

Comment: @MichaelUrman You are correct, of course, I'll adjust my phrasing